# onKeyDown - Control key is not working in Activity

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to add shortcuts in my app when external keyboard is connected. SHIFT+KEY, this combination is triggering the following event. But Control+KEY and Control key events are not triggered. Can anyone suggest me on this.

```
    @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT) {
                flag_sellreceipt = KeyEvent.isModifierKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT);
                int i = KeyEvent.META_CTRL_LEFT_ON;
                System.out.println("ctrl is pressed");
            }
            return

 super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

**Note:** I have tested this in emulator.

Comment: Well, With the Windows emulator I cant get any imput from Ctrl or Alt-keys, and no keys when alt or ctrl is pressed.

However with my old Samsung SM-T230 API19 with a Linocell 94059 Bluetooth keyboard I get key input both when ctrl and Alt keys are pressed, like ctrl-F, also in debugging, works fine. 

So I think it is an emulator issue.

Comment: I also get the 113 left ctrl-key.

Comment: The BT keyboard Enter and ESC looks like being processed by the OS ahead and never appears in the onKeydown, ESC change session, enter selects. But in the emulator nothing happens?? Partly it could be a keyboard implementation issue?

Comment: By the keyboard manufacturer